# Magento Enterprise does not create url redirects

Tags: magento

I have magento enterprise 1.13.0.2. Option `Use Web Server Rewrites` is enable. I know when category was created magento community automaticly creates url rewrites for this category. But I wonder why magento enterprice does not do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

301s have been removed on 1.13EE - you will have to rely on canonicals.

See [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12804/changing-product-category-url-key-doesnt-create-a-301-redirect-ee-1-13?s=fefef12e-ba5d-4956-9e6f-94ce7926f774) for more info.